# What is a JavaScript instance?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

What is an instance in JavaScript? Can anyone provide an example please?

Also, please explain your code.

Comment: How long before your exam finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an object !
Example:

```js
//instancing a image
var myImage = new Image(100, 100);
//Append in to body
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(myImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

An *instance* is simply an object that was created by a class (ES6) or constructor function. Here's an example:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var john = new Person("John Doe");
console.log(john);
//john is an instance of Person - we can see this by using the instanceof operator
console.log(john instanceof Person);
```

JavaScript makes instances when defining variables, but these are only accessible by using `typeof` unless you explicitly use the `new` constructor to make your variable:

```js
var str = "Foo Bar";
var num = 123;
var bool = true;
var obj = { abc: "def" }
var arr = [true, 1, "s"];

console.log(typeof str);
console.log(typeof num);
console.log(typeof bool);
console.log(typeof obj);
console.log(typeof arr);
console.log(typeof undefined);
console.log(typeof null);
```

There are a couple of tricks with `typeof` though - `typeof [] == "object"` because an array is an object with a few different methods. The other most common issue is `typeof null == "object"`, because of a discrepancy when JavaScript was created between `null` and `undefined`.

If you want to find the constructor of any value, use `constructor.name`:

```js
var str = "Foo Bar";
var num = 123;
var bool = true;
var obj = { abc: "def" }
var arr = [true, 1, "s"];

console.log(str.constructor.name);
console.log(num.constructor.name);
console.log(bool.constructor.name);
console.log(obj.constructor.name);
console.log(arr.constructor.name);
```

This trick also works with your own constructors and classes:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var john = new Person("John Doe");
console.log(john.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, in object-oriented programming, there are classes and objects. When you instantiate, or create an instance of a class, you get an object.

For example, take the following Car class:

```
function Car(myVin) {
    this.vin = myVin;
}

let myHonda = new Car(“24A6733HJ42983C55”);
let myFord = new Car(“JJ67100473KL93228”);
let momsMinivan = new Car(“JF293HJL679904611”);
```

You just instantiated the Car class three times. Each is an instance.

ES2015 (aka ES6) introduces the class keyword, and constructors:

```
class Car {
    constructor(myVin) {
        this.vin = myVin;
    }
}
```

This gets much more involved.

IMO, If you really want to learn OO programming, it’s really best to learn the C++ way first. There you’ll see classical inheritance at work, with concepts of constructors, private, protected, and public data members, design patterns, and other key concepts. This will build a solid foundation before you dive into the kluge that is Ecmascript classical inheritance.

Under the hood, Javascript has prototypical inheritance; Ecmascript plasters classical inheritance on top. It’s is a little weird and hacky, and have to do strange things with closures to achieve privacy.

See link below for a good lesson on OOP in C++.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vz1O9nRyZaY

Answer (score 0):

Let there be an object with properties `id`, `name`, and `age`. Now you want to create 100
objects that represent 100 people. Each person will have an `id`, `name`, and `age`.
You can create objects like:

```
var person1 = {
  id: 1,
  name: “p1”,
  age: 20
};

var person2 = {
  id: 2,
  name: “p2”,
  age: 21
};
….. And so on.
```

But instead of creating 100 objects by individually defining `id`, `name`, and `age` for all of
them, you create a standard template with properties `id`, `name`, and `age`. Then use
this template to create objects and set the required values.
This standard *template* can be seen as an object. Each time you create a new
object by using the `new` keyword, you create a new **instance** of an already-defined object with already-specified
properties.

For that, you can do this:

```
function people(id, name, age){
   this.id = id;
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
}

let people1 = new people(1,'rani',20);
let people2 = new people(2,'rahul',21);
let people3 = new people(3,'adi',20);
.
.
.
and so on.
```

Here `people1`, `people2`, and `people3` are the **instances**.